# pause()/kill() parent/child process. Parent keeps getting SIGTERM from child after first SIGTERM

Tags: c, signals, fork, kill, pause

What I am trying to do is create a child process that sends a signal to the parent whenever it's ready (after completing some task). When the signal is sent, the parent is unpaused and does some work and then pauses again waiting for the child to be ready again. The child after sending the signal, blocks and waits for my input before sending another signal to the parent process.

I want this to be repeated an arbitrary number of times. Below is my approach:

```
void sig_handler(int sig){
        if (sig == SIGTERM) printf("Working team is ready!\n");
        return;
}

int main(){
        //signal(SIGTERM,sig_handler);
        char*** orders;
        int NumOrders;
        if ((orders = importFileToArray(&NumOrders)) != NULL){
                SDFSort(orders, NumOrders);
                int i,j;
                for (i=0;i<NumOrders;i++){
                        for (j=0;j<4;j++){
                                printf("%s ", orders[i][j]);
                        }
                        printf("\n");
                }

                pid_t pid, ppid = getpid();

                if ((pid = fork()) == 0){
                        int choice = 1;
                        while(1){
                                sleep(1);
                                kill(getppid(),SIGTERM);
                                //do some work
                                scanf("%d", &choice);
                        }
                }else{
                        while(1){
                                signal(SIGTERM,sig_handler);
                                pause();
                                //do some work
                        }
                        wait(NULL);
                }

        }
}
```

Below is the output:

```
Working team is ready!
a
Working team is ready!
Working team is ready!
Working team is ready!
Working team is ready!
Working team is ready!
a
Working team is ready!
Working team is ready!
a
Working team is ready!
Working team is ready!
Working team is ready!
Working team is ready!
^C
```

As you can see it works well the first time (The parent blocks. The child sends the signal with the message "Working team is ready" and the parent unblocks. But then instead of blocking on the scanf it seems as if the child keeps sending signals to the parent while ignoring my input. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Task 1: Learn how to use `scanf`:  Fix your `scanf` parameter (you want to pass an address: `&choice`) Task 2: `scanf` returns a value, check it! Task 3: Now you will see that your child's `scanf` calls constantly fail after fork(). Do some more research why this is the case ;) Spoiler alert: It is going to be complicated!

Comment: @gollum 
Task 1: that somehow slipped when I copied the code. I use the reference in the original.
Task 2: I think it has to do with the stdin and how its passed from process to process. I ll check it out, thanks